# Where is the index.html on OSX 10.9 (Mavericks) Apache setup?

Tags: macos, apache

I've started up Apache on my Mac and get the "It works!" message, but I have no idea where that file is.

I've checked the httpd.conf file and the location listed is:

DocumentRoot "/Library/WebServer/Documents"

Yet, when I go to the /Library/WebServer/Documents folder, it is empty!

This one is driving me crazy, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you have homebrew installed? MAMP? Server.app? In fact can you just give us a list of what you do have installed? It sounds like you may not be using the default apache for os x.

Comment: have you restarted the server?
apachectl restart

Answer (score 10):

There should be 3 files in /Library/WebServer/Documents:

- index.html.en
- PoweredByMacOSX.gif
- PoweredByMacOSXLarge.gif

If these files are missing, it really shouldn't matter.

As soon as you create your own HTML file and place it in that folder, the "It works!" message should be replaced with your new index.html file.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Thomas, although I created a new html file, and still get the "It works!".  It has to be somewhere else, since no files even existed in that folder.

Comment: Is there a folder in the /Library/Server/Web/Data/Sites/ path called Default?

Answer (score 3):

copy index.html.en to just index.html and you'll be able to see your changed index.html file.

Just figured this out.

Answer (score 1):

There is a /Library folder in your account at:

`/Users/<username>/Library`

This is not the folder Apache uses.

There is a 'higher level' Library folder at :

`/Library`

and this will hold your apache Documents folder.

You can navigate 'higher' than your user folder by pressing down the Command key while clicking on the name of the folder that is centered at the top of the Folder window.

(Late answer, but it may be useful to someone...)